# How to know how many particular days of the week in the month are left from current day (including)

Tags: java

How to know how many particular days of the week in the month are left from current day (including)
For example today is 14.04.2015:
There are days of the week left till the end of the month :
Number of `Mondays` = 2
Number of `Tuesdays` = 3
Number of `Wednesdays` = 3
Number of `Thursdays` = 3
Number of `Fridays` = 2
Number of `Saturdays` = 2
Number of `Sundays` = 2

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution I've knocked up quickly using Java 8's `LocalDate` API. You'll need to unit test this:

```
public static void getDaysLeftInMonth() {
    LocalDate endOfMonth = LocalDate.now().with(TemporalAdjusters.lastDayOfMonth());
    DayOfWeek[] daysOfWeek = DayOfWeek.values();
    for (int i = 0; i < daysOfWeek.length; i++) {
        int numberOfWeekDaysLeftInMonth = 0;
        LocalDate now = LocalDate.now();
        while (now.with(TemporalAdjusters.next(daysOfWeek[i])).isBefore(endOfMonth)
                || now.with(TemporalAdjusters.next(daysOfWeek[i])).isEqual(endOfMonth)) {
            numberOfWeekDaysLeftInMonth++;
            now = now.plusWeeks(1);
        }
        System.out.printf("%d %sS left\n", numberOfWeekDaysLeftInMonth, daysOfWeek[i].name());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Really thanks a lot you Robert. I've just a little changed it to

```
public static void getDaysLeftInMonth() {
   LocalDate today =  new LocalDate("2015-04-22");
   LocalDate endOfMonth = today.dayOfMonth().withMaximumValue();;

    for (int i = 1; i <= 7; i++) {
        int numberOfWeekDaysLeftInMonth = 0;
        LocalDate now = today;
        LocalDate checkedDay = null;
        while ((checkedDay = now.withDayOfWeek(i)).isBefore(endOfMonth.plusDays(1)) ) {
            if (checkedDay.isAfter(today.minusDays(1))) {
                numberOfWeekDaysLeftInMonth++;
            }
            now = now.plusWeeks(1);
        }

        Log.d("TIME", String.format("%d - %d left\n",  i, numberOfWeekDaysLeftInMonth));
    }

}
```